# Internationalization of custom validation error messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I need to have custom validation messages in my `ActiveRecord` models internationalized. Currently, I'm using something like this, which works:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name, :message => lambda { I18n.t(:family_name_in_use) }
```

I know Rails has validation message translations builtin, but for reasons I can't go into here, I can't use those. Is there a nicer solution than this lambda thing? I'm using Rails 2.3.8, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately stuck with the `lambda` solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use builtin solution https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/ro.yml
And you can add translation of database attributes like this:

```
ro:
  activerecord:
    models:
      user: utilizator
    attributes:
      profile:
        name: "afişare Nume"
        phone: "telefon"
```